# Indicator to Draw a line and find out how many pips I can earn

Tags: forex

is there any indicator for mt4 where i can draw a line and it display how many pips and how much usd i could earn from point 1 (order opening time) to point 2 (order closing time)?
 
An example  :[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *is there any indicator for mt4 where i can draw a line and it display how many pips…?*

No, there is no such.

Nevertheless, it is possible to get one created for your specific use-case needs and preferences. Technically I would recommend it not to be implemented as a `CustomIndicator`-type of the `MQL4`-code, for technical reasons well beyond this post. The problem is definitely doable and MetaTrader 4 Terminal will serve you all the asked details on Man-Machine-Interface in a handy point-and-click fashion, if programmed well.